# string version of "false" does not equal true or false

Tags: javascript

the string of false `"false"` is not `true` or `false`:

```
"false" == true // false

"false" == false // false
```

how is this possible? this does not apply to `"true"`. The above results were executed in the chrome console panel.

**EDIT**

If the above does not evaluate to true then why does the bellow statement print hello:

```
if("false") console.log("hello")
```

**EDIT2**

In the linked duplicate it says `"false"` is converted to `NaN`. Let's test this in chrome shell:

```
if(NaN) console.log("hello")

if("false") console.log("hello")
// prints hello
```

But weirdly enough `isNaN("false")` returns true.

Comment: To get the string of `false`, you should use `String(false)`. That'll get you the expected result.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976714/converting-string-true-false-to-boolean-value, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23404028/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-using-boolean-type-versus-string-type-true-false

Comment: A string is a string. A Boolean is a Boolean. see [How can I convert a string to boolean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263965/how-can-i-convert-a-string-to-boolean-in-javascript)

Comment: @RonRoyston Sure, but "8" == 8 is true

Comment: Right, but "8" === 8 is False.

Comment: @RonRoyston Completely irrelevant since the question is not about the strict equality operator.

Comment: Regarding your edits, using a value in an `if` condition is a very different thing than comparing it to a boolean with the not typesafe equality operator.

Comment: doesn't an if statement check if that value evaluates to `true|false`?

Answer (score 1):

The empty string is falsey and every non-empty string is truthy.

`"true"` is not getting coerced to `true`, it's just an example non-empty string.

"0" is truthy (`if ("0") { true }` == `true`). But also `"0" == false`. That's because `==` coerces arguments to numbers and `"0"` becomes 0 and `false` becomes 0.

In general, never use the `==` operator in JS. Use `===` instead. If you want to use truthiness/falsiness of other values be careful :)

Comment: Then why `false == "0"` (which is clearly a non-empty string)?

Comment: Because JS coerces "0" to the number 0 because it's completely mad.

Comment: Before the edit, your sentence was correct. I just wanted to say that truthiness (and non-emptyness) have nothing to do with what happens when doing `== true`.

Comment: Thanks, Bergi. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

This does apply to "true" as well. Here "false" and "true" are same as any other string value in javascript, it does not have anything with boolean true or false value. Hence,

```
"true" == true is false
"true" == false is false
"false" == true is false
"false" == false is false
```

Comment: Some string values like `"1"` and `"0"` do have something to do with boolean values though.

Comment: @Bergi Agreed "1" and "0" have something with boolean values and it is very well expained here:

    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363659/why-does-true-true-show-false-in-javascript